# Trouble pulling multiple repos using GH actions, deploy key only works for composer file pulling from one repo how to automate several repos?

Tags: composer-php, github-actions

So I am trying to build a deploy action. I want to listen for a merge to a branch on any of several repos and when the merge happens I want to:

1. Checkout a specific branch
2. set the php version
3. run composer update (get the most recent hashes from all repos)
4. run composer install (clone all the repos locally)
5. deploy to Acquia

I have everything working until the action tries to check out the repos, I am getting a error:

```
Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@github.com:organization/repo1.git' '/home/runner/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-xxxxx.git/'

Cloning into bare repository '/home/runner/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-xxxxx.git'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'XXX.XX.XXX.X' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In the yaml I have:

```
name: composer update action
    uses: kawax/composer-update-action@master
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      GIT_NAME: myorganization
      GIT_EMAIL: myname@myorganization.edu
      COMPOSER_PACKAGES: north*
```

I have tried using php-composer-v6 but I get the same error. There are more than one repo so the deploy key does not seem to be the right solution.

here is an example of the repositories entries in the composer.json:

```
 "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:organization/repo1.git",
            "no-api": true
        },
        "1": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:organization/repo2.git",
            "no-api": true
        },
```

There are many repos - nine.

Comment: One way to deal with it are deploy keys. Perhaps you can create one for the organization and use it in your deployment pipeline. https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users

Comment: Deploy Keys. They are said to be only for use with one external repo and they require the creation of a rsa code generated from a server. The composer update action I am running is running on github not on an external server.

Comment: I tried to use the following entries in the plugin name: composer update action
        uses: kawax/composer-update-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          GIT_NAME: xxxxxxxx
          GIT_EMAIL: xxxxx@xxxxx.edu
          COMPOSER_PACKAGES: north* But no luck

Comment: Well create a single SSH key (generate it), then add a "bot" user to your organization, give it this SSH key and then add that user also to the other github repositories as collaborator. You just create one new user-account to delegate access. Compare as well again with the link in my earlier comment. When the action runs with that Github user acess to the repositories is given. Otherwise the action needs to have the SSH key which can be done with secrets comparable to the GITHUB_TOKEN.

Comment: @hakre that should be an answer